# Hide page paths and only show domain URL

Tags: html, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Is it possible to hide the page paths in the URL and only show the domain name without anything else?

So now I have multiple pages:

- `www.example.be/index.html`
- `www.example.be/travel.html`
- `www.example.be/links.html`
- ...

But on all the pages I only want to show `www.example.be` in the address bar.
I was looking into the `.htaccess` file but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: What is your motivation behind this? You can hide the URL-path using an `iframe`, as suggested in the current answer, however, this does not hide the URL-path from a user who views the page source or _inspects_ the page in their browser. (It's also bad for SEO and accessibility.)

Comment: @MrWhite if it shows somewhere else it is no problem. It is not to hide something. It is more to make the aesthetics in the address bar better. My father developt the website and his filenames are very ugly :) (One with capitals, the other with small letters and so on)

Comment: I thought I had an option to do it with the .htaccess file without changing the page itself

Comment: _“It is more to make the aesthetics in the address bar better. My father developt the website and his filenames are very ugly”_ - then refactor the whole thing, and make it use “better” ones. Hiding the complete URL path using (i)frames would lead to a massive _decrease_ in usability, for example bookmarking the current page the user is viewing, or sending that to someone else/sharing it on social media, all won’t be easily possible any more.

Comment: Bad "aesthetics" as you call it is much better than no URL-path at all (as pointed out above). Incidentally, you can't remove the URL-path entirely with `.htaccess` - the URL-path is required in order to identify a resource. If you request `example.com/` how does your server know whether to serve "travel" or "links"? But you can _change_ the URL-path using `.htaccess` to make it "look nice", without actually changing the underlying file path. Although you do need to manually change your actual internal links. But this is not necessarily a quick fix, depending on your site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your entire website in an iframe tag. And change the src property of the iframe dynamically using client side code. This way your page names won’t be visible in the url bar.

```
<iframe src="/index.html" height="200" width="300" title="Page Title"></iframe>
```